# Google Adsense API on multiple url but on same domain

Tags: adsense, google-ads-api

Is there any way to put multiple adsense API codes on same domain but on different urls?
Using different API keys to manage different adsense campaignes on same domain?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You mention API keys, but you seem to be talking about ad code (the little Javascript snippets you add to your page), which is entirely unrelated.